# Findstr error. FINDSTR: Cannot open

Tags: windows, command-line, findstr

I have 2 files. First csv file with email addresses and names **mail_list.csv**:

```
email,Name
name1@gmail.com,name1
name2@gmail.com,name2
name3@gmail.com,name3
name4@gmail.com,name4
name5@gmail.com,name5
name6@gmail.com,name6
name7@gmail.com,name7
```

And the second file with only email addresses **mail_list_to_remove.csv**:

```
name1@gmail.com
name4@gmail.com
name6@gmail.com
```

I would like to remove entries from **mail_list.csv** if email address exist in 
**mail_list_to_remove.csv** using findstr command.

When I'm trying simple commands like:

```
findstr @ mail_list.csv

findstr @ mail_list_to_remove.csv
```

I got proper results. But when I try below command:

```
findstr /g:mail_list_to_remove.csv /f:mail_list.csv
```

I got error message:

```
FINDSTR: Cannot open email,Name
FINDSTR: Cannot open name1@gmail.com,name1
FINDSTR: Cannot open name2@gmail.com,name2
FINDSTR: Cannot open name3@gmail.com,name3
FINDSTR: Cannot open name4@gmail.com,name4
FINDSTR: Cannot open name5@gmail.com,name5
FINDSTR: Cannot open name6@gmail.com,name6
FINDSTR: Cannot open name7@gmail.com,name7
```

Am I doing sth wrong or findstr is not proper tool to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: The `/F` option tells `findstr` that the file contains a list of files to search.  So it is looking for a file named `email,Name` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `findstr /g:mail_list_to_remove /f:mail_list.csv` instead